# Data incorrectly displayed - ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with the duplicate content in AngularJS.

My data which I download from the database:

See below what my table looks like, not as it should.

```
    {"records":[
{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"1","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"6930","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"2","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"10633","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"3","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"11282","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"4","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"8079","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"5","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"6245","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"6","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"5745","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"7","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"5897","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"8","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"5025","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"9","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"5024","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"10","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"6494","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"11","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"8083","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"12","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"6019","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"1","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"2450","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"2","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"2050","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"3","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1993","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"4","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1299","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"5","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1394","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"6","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1481","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"7","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1329","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"8","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"9","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"10","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"11","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"12","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"}
]}
```

My code.html

```
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <td>ROK</td>
               <th>1</th>
               <th>2</th>
               <th>3</th>
               <th>4</th>
               <th>5</th>
               <th>6</th>
               <th>7</th>
               <th>8</th>
               <th>9</th>
               <th>10</th>
               <th>11</th>
               <th>12</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tr>
             <td><span>2017</span></td>
             <td ng-repeat="x in analytics"><span ng-if="x.year == '2017' ">{{ x.organic_search_visit }}</span></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><span>2018</span></td>
             <td ng-repeat="x in analytics"><span ng-if="x.year == '2018' ">{{ x.organic_search_visit }}</span></td>
           </tr>
         </table>
```

View:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my code. The `ng-if` tag should be in `td` tag instead of `span` tag.
With your code there are some rows with no-content because of the `ng-if` placed into `span` tag.

```js
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);

module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
 $scope.analytics = [
{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"1","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"6930","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"2","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"10633","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"3","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"11282","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"4","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"8079","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"5","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"6245","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"6","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"5745","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"7","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"5897","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"8","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"5025","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"9","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"5024","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"10","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"6494","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"11","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"8083","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"12","year":"2017","organic_search_visit":"6019","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"1","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"2450","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"2","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"2050","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"3","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1993","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"4","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1299","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"5","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1394","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"6","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1481","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"7","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"1329","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"8","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"9","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"10","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"11","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"},{"id":"6","view_id":"111111111","month":"12","year":"2018","organic_search_visit":"0","domain_name":"abc.pl","opis":"123"}
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <td>ROK</td>
               <th>1</th>
               <th>2</th>
               <th>3</th>
               <th>4</th>
               <th>5</th>
               <th>6</th>
               <th>7</th>
               <th>8</th>
               <th>9</th>
               <th>10</th>
               <th>11</th>
               <th>12</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tr>
             <td><span>2017</span></td>
             <td ng-if="x.year == '2017'" ng-repeat="x in analytics"><span>{{ x.organic_search_visit }}</span></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><span>2018</span></td>
             <td ng-if="x.year == '2018'" ng-repeat="x in analytics"><span>{{ x.organic_search_visit }}</span></td>
           </tr>
         </table>
  </div>
</div>
```